# extjs 3.3: floating panel

Tags: extjs, panel, extjs3, floating

I am trying to create a floating panel over other pre-created panels, I tried following simple codes, but failed:

```
var testPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                                id: 'testP',
                                width: 50,
                                height: 100,
                                floating: true,
                                title:'Test'
                            });
testPanel.show();
```

what else I need to think about?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following needs to be taken care of when using the `floating` config:

1) Fixed width - which you've done
2) The position must be set explicitly *after render* (e.g., `myPanel.setPosition(100,100);`).

You can also set the underlying Ext.Layer config option instead of just setting `floating : true`. You can do that in the following way:

```
Ext.Panel({

  //.. other config..,
  floating : {
    //Ext.Layer config options. Maybe a property in that will get you the desired effect that you're looking for.
  }
});
```

Try this and update!

Cheers.