# Floating images in Sencha Ext

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I need to put multiple floating images in a container using extjs. The container itself should have a background or another image stretched to its sizes. All those images and background image should be dynamically changeable.

I managed to create the background image by simple Ext.image object included in the items of the container with `layout : {type: 'vbox', align: 'stretched'}`. But I failed to add floating images in it.

I tried the `floating: true` attribute but it results in not adding the element to the dom.
Also tried to add properties to the floating attribute following [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623370/extjs-3-3-floating-panel) but with no success.

On further reading on sencha's documentation found that floating in sencha acts differently. It actually hides the elements and shows them via ZIndexManager one at a time. Which is not what I was aiming for.

Is there any other way to make images floating in the container that also allows me to change their src and position in the container.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the trick is not making the images float but rather set the container's layout to absolute:

```
layout{
    type: 'absolute'
}
```

After that just set each element an x and y attributes like so:

```
var img = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
    src: 'whatever.jpg',
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
});
```

And they float. This also works if you set them percentage strings: '20%'