# Placing a textbox in extJS

Tags: extjs, textbox

I have a panel which when clicked displays a tree and a text box. But the problem is that it displays the textbox just below the tree .
Tree and textbox are two different function and on click they are being called back to back.

I want the textbox to be displayed at the right side of the tree.

How can I do that?[image: tree and textbox]

code of the textbox-

```
function textBoxTab(textBoxSubTab){
    var simple = new Ext.form.Panel({
        labelWidth: 75,
        frame:true,
        title: textBoxSubTab,
        width: 350,
        defaults: {width: 230},
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'tab',
                hidden: true,
                fieldLabel : textBoxSubTab,
                value:textBoxSubTab

            },
            {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'moduleId',
            fieldLabel: 'Module_id',
            allowBlank: false , // requires a non-empty value
            maskRe: /[0-9.]/

        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'moduleDesc',
            fieldLabel: 'Module_desc',
            allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
        }
        ],
        buttons:[
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                handler: function () {
                    this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Submit',
                handler: function () {

                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();

                    form.submit({
                        clientValidation: true,
                        url:"saveForm.htm",
                        success: function(form, action) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                        },
                        failure: function(form, action) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                        }
                    });
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        //Ext.Msg.alert('Submitted Values', form.getValues(true));
                        this.up('form').getForm().submit();
                    }
                }
            }]
    });

    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    mainPanel();
    panelAdmin();
    simple.render(document.body);

}
```

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox

Comment: @CD..I dont want to place 3 panels next to each other. These are two different things displayed on 2 function calls.Tree is displayed and then textbox function is called.So, is there a way that it gets displayed on right side of the tree

Comment: Have a look at `floating` the panels http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-floating

Comment: put them both in container, and as @CD.. mention before set the layout of the container to 'hbox'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  @RobSchmuecker mentioned in the comments we can use the "floating" attribute to do the desired .
You can find the detailed answer here.

[extjs 3.3: floating panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623370/extjs-3-3-floating-panel)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add **margin** to your panel

```
var simple = new Ext.form.Panel({
    labelWidth: 75,
    frame:true,
    title: textBoxSubTab,
    width: 350,
    *margin : 'up down right left'*
    defaults: {width: 230},
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'tab',
            hidden: true,
            fieldLabel : textBoxSubTab,
            value:textBoxSubTab

        },
        {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'moduleId',
        fieldLabel: 'Module_id',
        allowBlank: false , // requires a non-empty value
        maskRe: /[0-9.]/

    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'moduleDesc',
        fieldLabel: 'Module_desc',
        allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
    }
    ],
    buttons:[
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: function () {
                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function () {

                var form = this.up('form').getForm();

                form.submit({
                    clientValidation: true,
                    url:"saveForm.htm",
                    success: function(form, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                    },
                    failure: function(form, action) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                    }
                });
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    //Ext.Msg.alert('Submitted Values', form.getValues(true));
                    this.up('form').getForm().submit();
                }
            }
        }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried this but it did not work, my textbox panel is still displayed in the same way.